# Front-end for rdesktop

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, remmina, rdesktop

rdesktop is a powerful tool, that works amazingly well. It's just now, for normal people it's not really easy to teach that the user has to enter a long command in the terminal.

That's why I was wondering how to make such a powerful tool easy to use. Maybe with a DIY launcher? A window appears and ask for your username and password, and the rest is already definite.

In which programming language can I make something like that? I know that a batch file could be a solution, but I want to make it more user friendly.

Comment: I don't know rDesktop, but what is the command you have to run?

Comment: normally `sudo rdesktop -u userid@domain -p - -f mycompanyIP`

Comment: What does the cli ask for normally? Only the password?

Comment: rDesktop is remote desktop client. Ubuntu already has GUI for that - Remina.

Comment: Link to image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XMcMF.png

Comment: Yeah I know, but it have to be really easy to use, like just write your name and password, the rest have to be alerady configured.

Comment: Easy is a subjective term. Just writing name and password won't do anything unless you provide it your remote desktop server address. Closing it as too-localized